# request.ref is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I ran the node code on this site https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/sending-notifications-between-android.html by using:

```
node app
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: request.ref is not a function.
```

which corresponds to the following line:

```
sendNotificationToUser("username","new msg",function() {request.ref().remove();} );
```

This is my package.json file:

```
{
"name": "myApp",
"version": "1.0.1",
"description": "listen for addition of msgs",
"main": "app.js",
"scripts": {
"start": "node app.js",
"monitor": "nodemon app.js",
"deploy": "gcloud app deploy"
},
"author": "my name",
"engines": {
"node": "~4.2"
},
"license": "ISC",
"dependencies": {
"firebase": "^3.2.1",
"request": "^2.74.0"
 }
}
```

Comment: I think it's a typo in the tutorial, try `request.ref.remove()`

Comment: @MichaelBleigh I get this error on using 'request.ref.remove()' :
TypeError: Cannot read property 'remove' of undefined

Comment: Show us the rest of your code.

Comment: @ishmaelMakitla The code in app.js is same as that provided in the link.

Comment: The error might suggest that `request.ref` is `null` for some reason. Can you confirm that `var request = requestSnapshot.val();` actually returns a value (confirm that `request` is not `null`) - and in fact you might want to write a log statement to display the value of request.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are indeed some typos in the code. The actual version I run with uses this to remove the messages that have been sent:

```
requestSnapshot.ref.remove();
```

The entire `listenForNotificationRequests` method (in case I made any other edit mistakes while porting to the blog):

```
function listenForNotificationRequests() {
  var requests = ref.child('notificationRequests');
  requests.on('child_added', function(requestSnapshot) {
    var request = requestSnapshot.val();
    sendNotificationToUser(
      request.username, 
      request.message,
      function() {
        requestSnapshot.ref.remove();
      }
    );
  }, function(error) {
    console.error(error);
  });
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Frank , I still get some error while deploying to the server , could u help me out with 2 things:

Can u please provide me with the full corrected code of the blog post + code for using queues for sending notifications.

Comment: Frank, I wanted to ask you if I insert the required fields like API_KEY ,serviceAccount etc. ,add the required node modules, do npm install.

Will I be able to deploy my node app to heroku then
OR
Do I need to add stuff like express package.

Comment: I run the code as a simple node process. Since all requests come to the script through the Firebase database, it doesn't require a web server like express. I'd expect that such a node.js process is runnable on Heroku, but can't be of help there.

Comment: Frank u r awesome!